# swift multiple level navigation not seeing back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, storyboard

I'm having a problem that I can't find a solution to,
I have a multiple level navigation from on tableview to another:
Level 1: categories.
Level 2: Books.
Level 3: Chapters.
Level 4: Commentators

From level 1 to 2 every thing is working great.
From level 2 to level 3, there is no problem going forward but i am not getting the back button.

I don't know what code to show as it is kind of complicated, but i will try to describe the best i can.

This is the screenshot of the project right now:

[image]

I've read somewhere that you should use only one navigation controller but in the manuals i see multiple and can not figure out how to use it with only one with the storyboard anyway. so this is where i stand

the 4th level is not show as i can not pass the 3rd level back action.

After removing the second navigation controller this is the diagram:

[image]

But now i am having a problem with:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowChapters" {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            chapterStore = ChapterStore()

            let book = books[selectedIndexPath.row]

            //let chapters = chaptersController.allChap [selectedIndexPath.row].books   
            //let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewControlle as! ChaptersTableViewController
            destinationVC.chapterStore = chapterStore
            destinationVC.bookId = "\(book.id)"
            destinationVC.chapterId = nil
            destinationVC.pageNum = nil
        }
    }
}
```

can not go forward to the 3 level (chapters) from the books level, the segue is not firing. I think that was my initial problem and that what made me use the second navigation controller.

any one got any idea?

10x

Comment: Why do you think you need the second navigation controller?  If you were to present a second one it should be via a `show` segue, not a `push` segue

Comment: 10x, it is a show segue, in the dropdown: Show (e.g. Push), do i need to use the show details one? It is my first real world project and maybe i am missing something, can u explain please

Comment: Since it is a show segue, you have a modal presentation.  You don't see a back button because your final table view is the only view controller in your second navigation controller's stack.  You need to have a button on your final table view controller that calls `dismissViewController:animated:` or just have one navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was the problem...

After the help from @Paul and @Idan I did the following:

1. Removed the second navigation controller an shown in the second image in the question. that didn't work as i didn't have the forward option, but i remembered i forgot something else.
2. Added the following method to get the segue to work forward:

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowChapters", sender: self)

   }

I found that most of the times that i am doing a segue from a table view controller to a view controller with a table view in it, or the other way around i need both of the methods. when it is table view controller to a table view controller there is no need for this method, just the regular "prepareForSegue:sender" method, and i leave it i get two transitions for some reason...

Hoped this helped someone

Answer (score 1):

Since you are mixing `show` and `push` segues. You are having the issue. You can unwind to the first table view, but you cannot just unwind to 3 and still have the navigation controller in the same status as before (the back option will not work).

Your issues is circled in **red** instead of loading a new table, reload the data in the table. Keep using the same `UINavigationController` and your app will flow. [image: red circle]

Comment: 10x, can you explain is issue? i don't understand what to do as i can not find any manual for that, beyond the second level, 10x, ps. i understand that i am doing something wrong, that is obvious, but don't understand what is the issue and how to fix it

Comment: @ Erez I had lots of issues with it in the beginning. When you use `UINavigationController`, you create some kind of stack (and you always `push`). But once you use `modal` you replace your stack with a new view controller and cannot go back (well, you can but you lost the stack).

Comment: @Erez would you like me to add to the answer how to unwind to the first? or just looking for a way back to the 3rd?

Comment: I don't need to go from 3 to 1, form 3 i need to go to 2, and for 2 back to 1, just as the forward stack but backwards, or maybe it is more complicated then that? If i understand correctly (and i hope am not) when i go from 2 to 3 (the books to the chapters) i will loos the back to 1? i hope not. and i don't understand yet how to get the back button on 3 (chapters) do i need to remove the second navigation controller? and why do lots of manuals show two navigation controllers if it is not good? I'm kind of stuck at this point, 10x

Comment: You could have a second navigation controller, if it makes sense.  For example, In your app you might have a "settings" button.  You want this to open your app's settings and you might have hierarchical navigation in your app's settings.  On the settings navigation toolbar you could have a "close" button that immediately closes the settings, no matter how deep you are and returns to where you were in your main app.  The settings button would present a second navigation controller modally (as you are via closeand the close button would dismiss that navigation controller.

Comment: In your case, the second navigation controller doesn't make sense because chapters is a natural progression in the hierarchy

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11, you should not have second Navigation Controller. Just avoid using `modal` segue. Then you could go back and forward freely in your app.

Comment: I agree with both of you, but i am missing something here, i removed the second navigation controller and now the book to chapters segue is not firing, i have the image and code in the original question

Comment: @Idan, thank you for trying to help me but i don't understand what you are showing me, that is the sign i see always between the navigation controller and the next view controller, i am using the show (push) segue to move forward, can't find any other way to do the transition, any way, right now i am trying to use only one nav controller and it is working for level 1 to 2, but stop there (prev i could move to level 3 but now even that is not working)

Comment: @Idan I think now i understand what you wrote in the answer, but it is deferent tableviewcontroller, i can not reload the data to the same one, there are deferent model that taking part for each of the controllers, event the cell prototypes are total deferent.... as i understand the all meaning of the push to stack is that many view controllers can be pushed one over the other and there should be navigation between them, just kind find a way to do this in the storyboard

Comment: Found the problem for the forward issue after removing the second navigation controller, as it is a tablecell and not a button, i had to add the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method for it to work, now every thing is working great, 10x everyone